# Python list compreehension with restrictions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples like this (but much bigger):

```
t = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

I want a list with all the first elements of each tuple. I have:

```
first = list(x[0] for x in t)
```

Suppose I only want to add to 'first' a number if it's smaller than EPS. What I want is something like:

```
first = list(x[0] for x in t, x[0] < EPS)
```

But this is not a valid python statement.

I'd like to know what's the **pythonic** way of doing this (I can do it in the same way I'd do it in Java/C++, but I imagine there must be a better way.

Comment: You can just replace that comma with an `if`: `first = [x[0] for x in t if x[0] < EPS]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
[x[0] for x in t if x[0] < EPS]
```

Comment: @RocketDonkey: That's what you get for being a robot.

Comment: @Blender Haha, a robot that is still slower than most and usually has sub-par answers - wicked combo :)